# Find out what the secret is

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

`Now You have been tasked with a difficult puzzle. You cannont solve this puzzle, just give up, there is no Hope. This puzzle is much to difficult. Do not try to Find out what you need to do to solve The puzzle. The solution to this puzzle is very Secret. until you accept this you might spend 10 hours trying to solve this, perhaps even eleven. I/do not think you could solve it in 27/or even 2019. You might spend all day and night until 1:30pm before you give up. Others will Wait For you to solve the puzzle. But The puzzle will not be solved. All those who waited will eventually move on and go to the Next questoin.`

That being said, here is the puzzle:

`I Really do not know if Everyone can Do this. This is a difficult task that even HE cannot do. Him Reading about it may help. However, Reading will only get you so far. Despite all this, I do know that IN these lands Great things happen.`

I live on vancouver island.

[image: 1]

#1

> My grammar is not that great

#2

> Looking at source might help

#3

> You will have to wait for ~1h after the posting of this question before it makes sense (although it is technically possible to solve it before then)

#4

> Ask in the comments for more hints

Post question hints (easier to decipher):

#5

> Look at the thing that hint #2 reveals more closely

#6

> Look into hex editors

#7

> This question ties into another (or two)

#8

> hint 7 will become more clear at 10/27/2019 2:30pm Pacific time

#9

> The spaces in the binary have been removed, will have to re add them until all the characters are word characters

Originally a separate question, posted 10/17/2019 1:30pm

The puzzle:

There are nine cars. You are looking at The grey one. Just kidding this is not a riddle, I had to make time. The Last time I made One it was bad. This Is an enigmatic puzzle, but you can probably guess what is going on here. Sometime At a later date, someone will solve this puzzle. In fact, here's the rest:

[image: 3]

[image: 3]

I may as well have told you the whole thing.

I live on vancouver island.

Hints:

#1

> find the image

Originally another separate question asked 10/27/2019 2:30pm

Look at this picture:

[image: 4]

Hints:

#1

> https://hexed.it/ will help

Comment: Hi @MilesZew, welcome to Puzzling SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already! This looks like a great first post, good job! A note on the hints: it's generally preferred to give hints after some time has passed and nobody has made significant progress. Besides that, everything looks good. I hope this helps!

Comment: The second paragraph seems to be a RED HERRING ;)

Comment: @Avi  you found it :)

Comment: @MilesZew That's not the whole solution, I hope

Comment: @Avi no, certainly not

Comment: Alrighty, time is up. More hints, please :)

Comment: see hint #5 (let me know when you want the next one)

Comment: added hints 6 and 7

Comment: added hint 8 now

Comment: added 9. This one will make things make a lot more sense.

Comment: @avi I added more hints

Comment: _Nine_ hints within an hour of posting?!

Comment: @Gareth_McCaughan good point, I probably should have spaced them out. Then again most of the hints are half-hints or much too cryptic. Anyways, I will remember to give less hints in the future.

Comment: @Avi in case you are still interested, I made some important edits

Comment: The picture of the cat from the now deleted third puzzle appears as number 4 here, is this normal?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier it turns out that imgur was messing with the picture so I replaced it with a new one.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial(?) Solution:**

Looking at the imperfectly spelled words (and the numbers), we get:

> ```
>  You
>  cannont
>  Hope
>  to
>  Find
>  The
>  Secret
>  until
>  10/27/2019
>  1:30pm
>  Wait
>  For
>  The
>  Next
>  questoin
> ```
>
> Or, "You cannot hope to find the secret until 10/27/2019 at 1:30 p.m. Wait for the next question"
>  Presumably this means to "Ask in the comments for more" at 1:30 p.m. today, but for me it's after 3:00 p.m. already... perhaps there's some time-zone information hidden in the question that I don't see?

As for the second paragraph, taking

> all the capital letters that don't begin a sentence, you get:
>  `RED HERRING`

Comment: >! Good start. I forgot that other people live in different time zones (oops). I will edit my question to add that fact that it is in pacific time.

Comment: Isn't all the necessary information within the puzzle already? A [tag:semi-interactive-puzzle] is probably not a good idea.

Comment: You do not have to ask me anything to solve the puzzle, however It will get much more easy if you wait for "something"

Comment: I will avoid this type of puzzle in the future however, because it could kind of be classified as semi-interactive

Comment: @MilesZew No need - it's fine as long as it's logically solvable without interaction. People post hints *all* the time - the only requirement is that the puzzle can be solved without interaction.

Comment: (spoiler) ok. It does rely on something out of the question. However, the question does point to this other thing.

Comment: Are the "originally posted" things from a separate puzzle or part of this one?  The last one (the the S image) has rot13(prfne:22) in it.

Comment: More sleuthing finds this message rot 13(Xejwnu:Patp Patp:Sknzo->3,4,2,18 Sknz:Nalhwya 3nz sepd 1op pdaj 1op sepd hwop). This comes from rot13(dezzaj ej pda 2:30 eiwca)